# Getting FastStone Image Viewer open files with non-latin names

Tags: windows-7, image-viewer

I'm using Win7 Professional (German distribution). For images viewing, FastStone Image Viewer is my first choice. The program works fine unless images with non-latin filenames (e.g., Cyrillic, etc.) have to be opened. In that case, a home folder is opened and not the image itself. Note that Windows Image Viewer opens this kind of files with no problems. I presume there is an issue with encoding but the question is how to get it work on my German machine with FastStone Image Viewer. Thanks a lot in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

... it's basically not possible with the current version of FastStone. I've switched to IrfanView which deals with non-latin names faily well.

Answer (score 0):

The software has supported this since [version 5.4](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm#History), which added support for unicode filenames